# Why it can't deteck the tabel from my database

Tags: python, database, tkinter

The database code can't read my table from the DB Browser for SQlite app

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
import os
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random



def get_random_exercise():
# Fetch all exercises from the database
cursor.execute("SELECT exercise, reps FROM Biceps")
exercises = cursor.fetchall()

if exercises:
    # Randomly select an exercise from the list
    exercise = random.choice(exercises)
    exercise_name = exercise[0]
    reps = exercise[1]
    
    exercise_label.config(text="Exercise: " + exercise_name)
    reps_label.config(text="Reps: " + str(reps))
else:
    exercise_label.config(text="No exercises found.")
    reps_label.config(text="")

# Create a database connection
connection = sqlite3.connect("workout.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the main application window
bicep = tk.Tk()
bicep.title("Bicep Exercise")
bicep.geometry("500x800")
bicep.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# Create labels for exercise and reps
exercise_label = tk.Label(bicep, text="Exercise:")
exercise_label.pack()

reps_label = tk.Label(bicep, text="Reps:")
reps_label.pack()

# Create a button to generate random exercise
generate_button = tk.Button(bicep, text="Generate Exercise", command=get_random_exercise)
generate_button.pack()

bicep.mainloop()

# Close the database connection
connection.close()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RWZ1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n0GL.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wvwu.png

The code can't detect the table from the data base

Comment: According to those screenshots, the db file is in a different directory than the python code.  But `sqlite3.connect("workout.db")` looks in the **current directory** for the db file.  How do you expect the code to find the file, if you don't tell it the specific directory to use?

Comment: oh my god I frogot about that ty